# REST call with JSP - adding new entity to the database

Tags: jsp, rest, jpa

I have mapped the database with JPA. I have a JSP file with form that is getting all the necessary data to create a new user in the database. A REST web service handling calls and a function to create new user looks like that:

```
    @Path("entities.customer")
public class CustomerRESTFacade {
...
...
    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Response create(Customer entity) {
...
...
```

How should I call the function POST? Now, I get all the data with first jsp file, I am forwarding to another jsp file, where I create a Customer and set all the fields. But how can I call this POST method? Or maybe I have to send somehow the Customer object to web service and then there add it to the database ?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Since your resource accepts HTTP POST requests, you must make such a call to `/entities.customer`. It doesn't matter *who* makes this call as long as it contains XML or JSON that your JAX-RS implementation can map to a `Customer` instance.

Comment: how about adding a form to your jsp with action="/entities.customer" and method="post"?